# Add the current date to Android Studio strings.xml

Tags: xml, string, date, android-studio

I am still quite new to Android Studio, so I apologize if this is extremely simple.

Here is my string in my strings.xml:

```
    <string name="myCoupon">"Description: You have earned a free queso from
        Date Completed: "</string>
```

How do I put the current date in the last line?

Thanks!